# Python library/module for capturing user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, module

I've been working on a Tkinter game, and I've got the following problem:

I want to make a **Submit High-score** menu. But I want to make it so when you press **Enter**, the score gets submitted, not when you press a button. I am using Python 3.7, and yes, I am using the **Entry** widget.

So, if anyone knows any library/module or any function or method, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `bind` method to bind the Enter key (`Return`) to your `Entry widget`, which then calls the function you want to submit the score when the user hits Enter while in the entry widget:

```
entry_widget.bind('<Return>',function_to_submit_score)
```